# Add image to UINavigationBar with tintColor

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to add an image to a UINavigationBar that has a custom color. I was hoping to avoid having to use a .png for the entire thing, and to programmatically set the color, and drop the icon on top of the colored navigation bar.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

The `UIBarMetricsDefault` causes a repeat for the image icon, and I just want one in the center. The UIBarMetricsDefault and UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone settings are not working for me, and I was hoping someone would know a better suggestion.

I am trying to avoid using a .png for the entire navigation bar, and would like to add the image to a color that is set programmatically. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you set color is correct. 
To set image in center use `titleView` property of navigationItem as shown below :

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"]];
```

Comment: Thank you!! Exactly what I was trying to do :)